# How do you internationalize the message being thrown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base  
...
  validates_presence_of :name, :message => "cannot be blank.
...
```

I am looking for ways to internationalize the message so that a localized message is shown from users from a different locale. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rails Guides: Translations for active records](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) will give you a hint about it. Basically, you don't have to store the string in your model. You can change it in your locale files.

Answer (score 1):

I18n is one of the good way to internationalize the message.

But if your message customization level is too much then every time you need to modify the ymls and also need to add new yml for different set of users.

In such case you can use '*redis*' it gives you more dynamic control. It store data in key => value hash. It is really fast. Following links will help youl

http://redis.io/documentation

http://jimneath.org/2011/03/24/using-redis-with-ruby-on-rails.html

https://github.com/jodosha/redis-store

http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2009/key-value-stores-for-ruby-part-4-to-redis-or-not-to-redis/

Comment: Why should I be using a different yml for different set of users and I don't understand the reasoning behind using redis to solve this issue.